# Chessbase 13 for automatic game analysis

Tags: chessbase

How can I use ChessBase 13 for automatic game analysis? I am new to ChessBase 13 and I don't understand its functions completely.
I have more than 1 chess engines installed manually

This is related to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27/is-there-any-free-software-to-automatically-analyze-and-annotate-games/1099#1099) question where the answer given is ChessBase but not described how to use it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have Chessbase, so this is just a comment. I think Chessbase is simply a database software. You'd need Fritz to do a full-game or blunder check analysis.

Comment: But as per the link given in the question to another question the top answer given is chessbase , what is the significance of that ?

Comment: Chessbase is the name of the company and also the name of the product. The answer might refer to the company itself, not exactly the product.

Comment: Well in that sense the answer means u send game to company to analyze ?,that's strange.

Comment: No. I meant Chessbase is a company. They also make a product called "Chessbase". The Chessbase software is a database GUI without a chess engine installed. You'll obviously need a chess engine to do full-game analysis.

Comment: Well I have more than 1 chess engines installed manually (and it has fritz already installed with it), but none of the functions do the automatic  analysis.

Comment: I see you EDITED. I believe you have not installed any chess engine and therefore nothing to analysis.

Comment: @ student T : i have many engines installed see my edit

Comment: I can see your engines... I have some of those installed but I can use the analysis feature... I fail to see anything. I think you'll need to email Chessbase.

Answer (score 3):

The company ChessBase sells a series of engine GUIs (Fritz, Houdini, Komodo, Rybka) that blundercheck or do full game annotation. The ChessBase program lets you run an engine while you go through a game, or can add games with a similar opening, but it won't do an automatic full game analysis the way that the engine GUIs do.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a game into ChessBase and you save the game, right click the game slot (in the database in which you saved it.

Under "Edit" ==> "More" ==> Editorial Annotation (RR). This will allow ChessBase to go through its database and give you an annotated game, according to past players, lines, etc.

However, I believe you will need a "Big Games" database for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ChessBase 13, but in ChessBase 16 you simply go to the "Analysis" tab at the top and select either "Tactical Analysis" (for blunders) or "Centipawn Analysis" (for best engine moves).

[image]

Comment: yes, it is correct and it is available on older versions too, you can have different engines each time analyze your game for you

Answer (score 0):

New board, paste your game in, click analysis tab, click "Let's Check Analysis" (third button from left at the top).  Choose the options (try each one if you don't know what they do), and start.

Comment: You seem to be talking about Fritz rather than Chessbase 13.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way (but imperfect) to analyse full games in ChessBase, using the Let's Check feature.

1. Open your game
2. Click on the analysis tab and enable Let's Check.
3. Click on Let's Check analysis, and choose for example Standard Analysis (in advanced settings, you can set the analysis time per move). If a given move has already been analyzed by other users, ChessBase will just retrieve the analysis and no calculations are made. If not, it will use your own engine.

See https://uscfsales.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/chess-game-analysis-using-fritz13s-%E2%80%9Clets-check%E2%80%9D/
for other details.

Comment: Your link points to the engine GUI Fritz which is distinct from the database program Chessbase 13, which is what the OP was asking about.  Chessbase 13 does not have the Let's Check feature; only the recent engine GUI's do.