# An offline alternative to lichess.org's online analysis engine

Tags: analysis, software

Lichess.org has probably the best chess analysis interface. But, the problem it works only online.

Whereas, Stockfish the engine behind the analysis is downloadable, the interface is not.

I am looking for an analysis software (preferably open source and free) that uses traditional engines and can provide data such as number of blunders, mistakes, inaccuracies etc,. And, preferably with graphs and statistics like lichess.org.

The reason for open source is that so it can be compiled across several operating systems. And, most importantly, can be modified to suit individual needs.

Comment: Within which O.S. would it need to operate?

Comment: @CharlesRockafellor I added the information you requested. :)

Comment: Stockfish does have an interface (at least the one on mac) but I don't know if they have statistics.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27/is-there-any-free-software-to-automatically-analyze-and-annotate-games

Comment: @chackerian I already read that; most of the suggested software is not free or does not run on multiples OSes, SCID runs on Linux as well and is open source but does not provide automatic annotations or statistics such as blunders etc,. like lichess.org.

Comment: @chackerian Stockfish is also used by lichess.org itself.

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend SCID. Its open source and very feature rich.

Answer (score 1):

Scid vs PC has the ability to annotate games:

http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Analysis.htm#Annotating

Answer (score 1):

[LucasChess](https://www-lucaschess.rhcloud.com/) Has a great anlysis interface and is also open source